# How to get start and end date

Tags: c#, date

I am supposed to append the excel sheet with start and end date.
Start date would be the last weeks Saturday and end date would be the current weeks Friday.
This should be done on weekly basis..
Only on Every Monday the new start and end date should be appended automatically.
How can i get the dates as for my requirement.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is running **only on Monday** you can use this :

```
DateTime lastWeekSaturday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
DateTime thisWeekFriday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4);
```

You can extract your desired part from these DateTime objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   DateTime startOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
   DateTime lastWeekSaturday = StartOfWeek.AddDays(-1);
   //Console.Write(lastWeekSaturday);
   DateTime currentWeekFriday=  DateTime.Now.AddDays(5 - (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
   //Console.Write(currentWeekFriday);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/34U6Pn)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some magic code :D

```
if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    DateTime lastWeekSaturday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Saturday - 1 - 7);
    DateTime lastWeekThursday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Thursday - 1 - 7);
    DateTime lastWeekTuesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday - 1 - 7);

    DateTime thisWeekFriday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Friday - 1);
    DateTime thisWeekThursday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Thursday - 1);
    DateTime thisWeekTuesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday - 1);

    DateTime nextWeekTuesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday - 1 + 7);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Its not monday");
```

Just `-7` to go back a week and `+7` to go forward a week. I think you will be fine with the examples i provided.